# Name of section in titleformat

Tags: sectioning

When I try the titleformat commands with my sections, the name of the section doesn't appear.

```
\titleformat{\section}[wrap]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
```

As result with this code, I get this[image: Numbering without name of section]

Could someone explain me why?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[wrap]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
%\titlespacing{\section}{-1.5cm}{0cm}{0cm}%1=command,2=leftmargin,3

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapitre} % (fold)
    \label{cha:chapite}
    \section{Section} % (fold)
    \label{sec:section}
    \section{Secondth section} % (fold)
    \label{sec:secondth_section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, present a minimal document showing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your `\section` titles are not being displayed is because you're passed the `explicit` option to the package `titlesec`:

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
```

In such cases, you have to `explicit`ly use `#1` within the definition of `\titleformat` to place the title that is being used. Without that, the title is gobbled.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\thesection. #1}{0.5em}{}% <--- #1 denotes \section title

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{First section}

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

Even though I've changed the `\section` title format from `wrap` to `display`, that doesn't make a difference in terms of the use of `#1` under `explicit`.